# Is it possible to use the name of a class as the key of a new type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I want to use the name of a class (which is provided as a variable) as the property for a wrapped component. But I'm not sure how to do this with typescript.

So in short: The name of the key of the object (a string) would be derived from the name of the class.

Here's an example:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {
    get name():string {
        return 'test';
    }
}

//Then I'm looking to create a function with a type declaration like this 
//don't worry about the implementation, the bit that matters is T.toString()..
var convert:<T extends Animal, P={}>(
    type:T,
    component:React.FC<P>,
  )=> React.FC<P & {T.toString().toLowerCase():T}>;

//so that I can do this:
const MyComponent = convert<Dog>(Dog,({dog:Dog}) => {
    //the converted component receives a 'dog' property of the type Dog
    return <div>{dog.name}</div>;
}
```

Is this possible in typescript? How would I declare the convert function?

Comment: It isn't possible, but if you declare a static readonly property on the class, then you could probably make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my comment implemented now:

```
class Animal {
  static readonly NAME: string;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  static readonly NAME = "dog";

  get name(): string {
    return "test";
  }
}

// Declare `T` as an Animal constructor that also has a NAME
declare const convert: <T extends { new (...args: any[]): Animal; NAME: string }, P = {}>(
  type: T,
  component: React.FC<P & Record<T["NAME"], InstanceType<T>>> // use the NAME and set it to an instance of the constructor
) => React.FC<P & Record<T["NAME"], InstanceType<T>>>;

const MyComponent = convert(Dog, ({ dog }) => { // now OK
  return <div>{dog.name}</div>; // 'dog' is now type Dog
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbQrEN)

Comment: Still requires a bit of extra code, but as close as it gets, and it works. thanks for writing out the answer!